# CASE Statement Force an Error Message as a Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to implement this sort of logic:

```
select
     many_columns,
     case
          when something then 'whatever'
          else Generate Error Message and Stop the Query
     end as [whatever]
from
     table_1
```

Is this possible?

**Edit #1:**

Based on the comments that I got, I did some experimenting.

```
drop table if exists #testing;
go

    with whatever as (
        
            select 1 as [num] union
            select 2 union
            select 3 union
            select 4 union
            select 5 union
            select 6 union
            select 7 union
            select 8 union
            select 9 union
            select 10
        
        )
    
declare @counter INT
set @counter = 0

while (@counter <= (select count(*) from #testing))
begin
    IF (@counter) < 5
        print 'hi'
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    else
        select * from #testing
        print 'bye'
        select @counter = @counter + 1
end
go
```

Hmm...the If statement is having issues with the else part...all I get is "Incorrect Syntax".

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that returns a single, atomic value. It is **NOT** a construct to deal with program flow and such - for that, you need to use `IF / ELSE`

Comment: You would need to carry out your error test as a separate action to the select. Or you could add an error column to the select. How you are using this outside the query would determine the best approach.

Comment: I have never used an IF statement inside of SQL before. I'm going to edit my post in a second. Interesting. Guess who learned something new? #this_guy

Comment: `IF EXISTS (select 1 from #testing where [num] < 5`)` ?

Comment: I haven't implemented this type of logic before in SQL. I'm trying to integrate an If statement with a while loop, one sec.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer to my question is to combine a `while` loop with an `if` statement AFTER producing my main query to find the error message.

The final if statement will look something like this:

```
declare @counter INT
set @counter = 0

while (@counter <= (select count(*) from #testing))
begin
    --print @counter
    IF (@counter = (select [num] from #testing where [num] = @counter))
        --print 'hi'
        print cast(@counter as varchar) + ' ' + 'hi'
    else
        --select * from #testing where [num] = @counter
        --print 'bye'
        print cast(@counter as varchar) + ' ' + 'bye'
    select @counter = @counter + 1
end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't put it better than the comment from @marc_s:

> `CASE` in T-SQL is an expression (like `a+b`) that returns a single, atomic value. It is **NOT** a construct to deal with program flow and such - for that, you need to use `IF / ELSE`

So let's take your original [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) code:

```sql
case
  when something then 'whatever'
  else Generate Error Message and Stop the Query
end as [whatever]
```

As an [`IF/ELSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) (using [`BEGIN/END`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-end-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) flow:

```sql
IF call_that_a_knife = 'yes'
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'This is a knife' AS yes_i_call_that_a_knife;
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('That's not a knife!', 16, 1);
  END
;
```

[`RAISERROR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql)

Comment: Better to use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`

Answer (score 0):

The way I have implemented this kind of construct is by attempting to perform an addition operation with the error message in case the condition for the error is true:

```
select
     many_columns,
     1 + case
          when <error_condition> 
          then 'Error Message Here will Stop the Query'
          else 0 end as [success]
from
     table_1
```

Assuming that the `<error_condition>` uses data from the rows fetched from `table_1` or calls out some function that returns a value that may mean an error condition, this will run the query until it reaches the point the condition is `true` and then will error out with something like:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Error Message Here will Stop the Query' to data type int.
```